# What is the difference between initializing a Float with a String, or doing parseFloat?

Tags: java

While coding a quick application, I noticed that there are two ways you could convert a String into a Float or an Integer.

```
Float f = new Float("0.0327f");
Float f = Float.parseFloat("0.0327f");
```

Similar methods exist for Integers.
How are these two different?

Comment: Nothing, they both use same underlying API.

Comment: You are hiding the subtle difference by using `Float` instead of `float` in the second line. It works, of course, but the return type of the methods is different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check their implementation (Oracle JDK 7)

```
public Float(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    // REMIND: this is inefficient
    this(valueOf(s).floatValue());
}
```

where `valueOf(String)` is

```
public static Float valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return new Float(FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(s).floatValue());
}
```

while `parseFloat(String)` is

```
public static float parseFloat(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(s).floatValue();
}
```

In the end, the two ways to generated the `Float` are equivalent. I say equivalent because in your example,

```
Float f = Float.parseFloat("0.0327f");
```

the `float` result of `parseFloat` will be boxed to a `Float`. The [boxing process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) will basically wrap the previous call, ie. `Float.valueOf(Float.parseFloat("0.0327f"))` and the resulting `Float`'s reference will be assigned to `f`.

Comment: The implementation may be almost the same, but the class constructor creates an instance of the `Float` class, while the other returns a primitive `float`.

Comment: @Luiggi Right, which is why I say they are equivalent. The implementations speak for themselves.

Comment: _The implementations speak for themselves._ But that may not be clear to someone new. It would be nice to have an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much difference, the first explicitly creates a new Float from input string, the second creates a new Float too but thru autoboxing since Float.parseFloat returns primitive float. Internally both use the same mechanizm to parse input string.